# How do i add set of numbers to specific one index in a List<float>?

Tags: c#

```
int numberofframesX = 0;
int numberofframesY = 0;
string framesX = "";
string framesY = "";
string X = "";
string Y = "";
string t = path + "\\" + fileName;
OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(t);
string XX = setting_file.GetKey("Number Of Frames X");
string YY = setting_file.GetKey("Number Of Frames Y");
numberofframesX = Convert.ToInt32(XX);
numberofframesY = Convert.ToInt32(YY);    

for (int i = 1; i < numberofframesX ; i++)
{
    X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i);
    framesX = setting_file.GetKey(X);
    List<string> floatStrings = new List<string>(framesX.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
    List<float> test = new List<float>(  floatStrings.Select(tempStr => (float)Convert.ToDouble(tempStr)).ToList()); 
    wo1.woc.Point_X = test; 
}
```

I need to do what its shown like in the two images in the links below in the bottom of my question. woc index [0] have two Lists of float allready i need that in Point_X to add the numbers each number to an index in the Point_X for example frame 1 is Frame_X_1 so the numbers near it on the right should have been added ot Point_X indexs then in woc[1] Frame_X_2 and so on.....

This is the text file ( setting_file)

```
Frame_X_1 =323,332,322,332
Frame_Y_1 =206,212,218,203
Frame_X_2 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_2 =206,212,269,203
Frame_X_3 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_3 =206,212,269,203
Frame_X_4 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_4 =206,212,269,203
Frame_X_5 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_5 =206,212,269,203
Frame_X_6 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_6 =206,212,269,203
Frame_X_7 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_7 =206,212,269,203
Frame_X_8 =323,332,318,332
Frame_Y_8 =206,212,269,203
Number Of Frames X=4
Number Of Frames Y=4
```

And this is the code of woc WireObjectCoordinates class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AnimationEditor
{
    class WireObjectCoordinates
    {
        public List<float> Point_X = new List<float>();
        public List<float> Point_Y = new List<float>();

        public WireObjectCoordinates()
        {
        }

        public WireObjectCoordinates(WireObjectCoordinates w)
        {
            Point_X.AddRange(w.Point_X);
            Point_Y.AddRange(w.Point_Y);
        }

        public void Set(WireObjectCoordinates w)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Point_X.Count; i++)
            {
                Point_X[i] = w.Point_X[i];
                Point_Y[i] = w.Point_Y[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And GetKey function from the setting_file(OptionsFile) class:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : GetKey
 * Description  : gets the value of the key.
 * Parameters   : key
 * Return       : value of the key if key exist, null if not exist
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public string GetKey(string key)
    {

      //  string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line;
        string line;
        int index;
        string key_value;
        key_value = null;

        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {


            index = line.IndexOf("=");


           //    value_of_each_key = line.Substring(index+1);



            if (index >= 1)
            {
                key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
                if (key_of_each_line == key)
                {
                    key_value = line.Substring(key.Length + 1);
                }

            }
            else
            {
            }


        }
        sr.Close();
        return key_value;
    }
```

I added now two images of how WOC and Point_X and Point_Y should look like:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/imag0649b.jpg/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/imag0648me.jpg/

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. It's *really* hard to read at the moment, with the indentation all over the place.

Comment: On a side note: You might want to consider using `Convert.ToSingle(tempStr)` instead of `(float)Convert.ToDouble(tempStr)`

Comment: What is the rule for grouping the frames?

Comment: Additionally, are you sure you don't want to start your FOR loop with 'i = 0'? Currently, you are skipping your first frame.

Comment: Post the code that declares `wo1` without this information your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Babak i want to start the loop with i = 0 but when i run my application im getting error since the variable framesX is nuul on the line = setting_file.GetKey(X); i will  add to my question an example of the setting_file text file.

Comment: So is your question how do I add more numbers to a list of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a `List<List<float>>`. Or if your sets of floats are fixed, you could probably use `List<float[]>`

Comment: Bali C i tried : List<float[]> test = new List<float[]>(  floatStrings.Select(tempStr => (float)Convert.ToDouble(tempStr)).ToList()); but dosent work. Could you show me what did you mean in my code ?

Comment: WAIT !! a little my mistake. I need that in woc index [0] in Point_X i will have the numbers of Frame_X_1 in every index of Point_X like [0] 332 [1] 333 [2] 444 [3] 443 then in woc index [1] in Point_X in index [0] 11 in [1] 12 and so on....

Comment: @user1526380: the idea behind this is that you would make `Point_X` into a `List<List<float>>`. Then you could do `Point_X.Add(test)`. Essentially Point_X has to be of a type that can hold the data you want it to. At the moment it looks like it is just a List<float> whcih won't do it so you change its type to somethign more suitable.

Comment: @user1526380: I think you might want to update your question with details on the structure of this woc object... At the moment it doesn't have any obvious indexes...

Comment: Updated my question also added two links for two images to show how it sohlud be.